# Get object of associations and not the assignment objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5 app.
In this app I got three models, User, Assignment, Goal.

A user can have many goals through assignments.

**Assignment**

```
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "assignable_type"
    t.integer  "assignable_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_account_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["assignable_type", "assignable_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_assignable_type_and_assignable_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

**Goal**

```
create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "gtype"
    t.datetime "starts_at"
    t.datetime "ends_at"
    t.string   "status",      default: "ontrack"
    t.string   "privacy"
    t.integer  "progress",    default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_goals_on_account_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["goal_id"], name: "index_goals_on_goal_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_goals_on_team_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

I want to get all the assigned Goals for a specific user. How can I do that?

If I do the following I only get the Assignment objects and not the goal objects.

```
u = User.last
u.assignments
```

**Result**

```
#<Assignment id: 2, account_id: 1, user_id: 1, assignable_type: "Goal", assignable_id: 1, created_at: "2017-12-27 16:35:54", updated_at: "2017-12-27 16:35:54">
```

**I want to get**

```
#<Goal id: 6, account_id: 1, user_id: 1, team_id: nil, goal_id: nil, title: "asdf", description: "asdfdf", gtype: "company", starts_at: "2017-12-31 00:00:00", ends_at: "2017-12-31 00:00:00", status: "ontrack", privacy: "public", progress: 0, created_at: "2017-12-27 17:36:59", updated_at: "2017-12-27 17:38:41", ancestry: nil>
```

Comment: Why not use `User.last.goals`?

Comment: I think I solved it by adding this to the User class. has_many :goals, through: :assignments, source: :assignable, source_type: 'Goal'